# Why is there a NameError in this list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Could you please explain, why this code works in Python 3.6

```
class B:
    a = 'a_val'
    b = {'a': 'a_val: {val}'.format(val=a)}
```

but this doesn't work?

```
class C:
    a = 'a_val'
    b = {i: 'a_val: {val}'.format(val=a) for i in range(0,2)}
```

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

and both classes work in Python 2.6.

Comment: Python 2.6 doesn't have dict comprehensions, so class C isn't going to even compile in 2.6.

Comment: BTW, even if you can't avoid using Python 2 for some reason, you probably shouldn't be using old-style classes.